# turning Ubuntu off

Tags: 12.04

In order to turn system off I have to turn the power off.  When I click on my user name in upper right hand corner the system shut down menu does not appear in Ubuntu 12.04. I upgraded from 11.04 to 12.04.  If do click on my user name it asks me to log in and also asks if I want to shut down.  When I click shut down nothing happens

Comment: When you click your Username? You should be heading for the bottom item on the menu that appears after clicking on the little cog icon (top-right).

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf-editor. Run it at the command line by 'dconf-editor' and refer to the following figure : 
[image]